# Howto: Conditional include of header file

Tags: linux, compilation, shared-libraries

I have test.c in which I would like to have the statement

`#include "abc.h"` (the header file of libabc)

only if test.c has been compiled with libabc as:

`gcc test.c -labc`

If test.c is simply compiled as

`gcc test.c` , abc.h should not be included.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use `-D` to define a macro:

```
gcc test.c -labc -DABC

#ifdef ABC
#include "abc.h"
#endif
```

If you're running this command from Bash, then you could in principle create a shell-function wrapper around `gcc` to automatically add `-DABC` when `-labc` is specified:

```
function gcc ()
{
    local arg
    for arg in "$@" ; do
        if [[ $arg = -labc ]] ; then
            command gcc "$@" -DABC
            return
        fi
    done
    command gcc "$@"
}
```

. . . but I don't really recommend that.

Comment: +1 for the idea. I don’t recommend either, but that’s creative.

Answer (score 1):

Hardly, as the link phase takes place after the compilation is done. You could tweak a Makefile to define a preprocessor macro, and use it as a test condition. I can’t think of any other way.